# Ubuntu on Windows 10: pip cache folder not owned by current user

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, lxss

I'm on Windows 10 Pro, using the Linux Subsystem with Ubuntu 18.04 'app' from the official store.

The problem:

```
$ sudo pip install ansible

The directory '/home/realtebo/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory 
is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please 
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip 
with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

*Please note that the module has been succesfully installed*, my question is only about the warning

I tried

```
$ sudo rm /home/realtebo/.cache -rf
```

This deleted the folder,  but the problem about directory owner is still here

Obviously /home is of root

```
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root   512 Jul 25 23:01 home
```

But the /home/realtebo is mine

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 realtebo realtebo 512 Aug  2 07:15 realtebo
```

Can you explain me the problem source? 
Should I install pip packages as user instead of using `sudo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of the problem or warning is that you are installing ansible using sudo and the way in which sudo works.

Sudo elevates your privileges so that you can install packages and do things **with root privileges**.  But, that is **not exactly the same as being root**.  https://www.sudo.ws/

For example, if you do

```
sudo su -
```

and enter a full root session and then do

```
pip install ansible
```

then the warning doesn't happen.

As to whether to install the packages as user, instead of sudo, or to even do **sudo su -** and install from a root session, that depends on exactly how you want to work and maintain your python environment.

Ideally, you probably also want to be using virtualenv( https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)